# 'Not a valid Base64 String when verifying hashed password

Tags: c#, security, authentication, passwords

So I'm running the following setup once a user logs in:

When a new user is created, the password gets a generated hash and is concatenated with newly generated Salt. The HashedPassword + Salt is stored in a column separate from the Salt column. I then call method `VerifyHashedPassword(string storedHashedPass, String password)` `storedHashedPass` is the stored hashed password (with the salt) and `password` is the plaintext password the user has entered at login with the concatenation of the salt retrieved from storage.

But when I try and implement this, it throws `'System.FormatException'`

can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
 public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string hashPassword, String password)
 {
      return System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashPassword, password);
 }

 public static string GetSalt()
 {
      var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

      int max_length = 32;

      byte[] salt = new byte[max_length];

      random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);

      return Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
  }

 public static string hashPassword(string password)
 {
      return System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.HashPassword(password ?? "");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HashedPassword + Salt is stored in a column

That is probably the root problem. You don't need to provide or handle a Salt. See [this answer](http://%20stackoverflow.com/a/17758221/9695604).
You should not need a `GetSalt()` method.

You can't simply concatenate 2 base64 strings, the decoder doesn't know how to handle that.

Comment: So what I get from this is that I don't need to concatenate the salt to the password field as the decoder already knows what part of the hashed password is salt? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is how it is documented. How could VerifyHashedPassword() work, otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

The Base64 format stores 6 bits per character. Which, as bytes are 8 bits, sometimes some padding is needed at the end. One or two `=` characters are appended. `=` is not otherwise used.

If you concatenate two Base64 strings at the join there maybe some padding. Putting padding in the middle of a Base64 string is not valid.

Instead concatenate the byte arrays, and then encode.